# Closure of the interior of the epigraph

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, continuity, convex-analysis

Suppose $f:E\to(-\infty,\infty]$, where $E$ is a Banach space, is lower semi-continuous, convex, and the interior of $epi(f)\neq\emptyset$. Show that $\overline{int(epi(f))} = epi(f)$
\begin{equation} epi(f) = \{ (x,t) : f(x) \leq t\} \end{equation}
I already showed that if $f$ is lsc, $epi(f)$ is closed. Does it mean the closure of the interior of a closed set is the set itself? If not, how can I do the problem?

Thank you.

PS: I am not good at topology.

Comment: Yes, the closure of the non-empty interior of a closed convex set is the set itself in any linear topological  space. You can find this result in Holmes: "Geometric Functional Analysis and its Applications" on p. 59 and its proof is based on the continuity of the operations.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ be a closed set on a topological space.

$\overline{X}=X$ and $X^{\circ}\subset X$,(here $X^{\circ}$ denotes the interior), hence $\overline{X^{\circ}}\subseteq \overline{X}=X$.

But the other inequality doesn't hold in general, as an example think on any isolated point $\{r\}$ in the reals with the usual topology, its interior is empty and so is the closure of its interior.

In this case, the interior is not empty (by hypothesis) and we can prove the equality just by taking the set of limits of sequences in $int(epi(f))$ and prove they all lie on $epi(f)$.

Comment: A quick question. What is the difference of a point, say $(x,t) \in int(epi(f))$, and $(x,t) \in epi(f)$? Do they have the same property that $f(x) \leq t$? Thank you.

Comment: $(x,t)\in int(epi(f))\Rightarrow f(x)<f(t)$,
$(x,t)\in epi(f)\Rightarrow f(x)\leq f(t)$
But try to prove it if you don't see it clearly.